# Restrict delegate to fire event only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have html that looks like below:

```
<div>
    <a class="SameClass">One</a>
    <a class="SameClass">Two</a>
    <a class="SameClass">Three</a>
    <a class="SameClass">Four</a>
</div>
```

I want to register click event using delegate, which ended me up writing some code like below:

```
$("div").delegate($(".SameClass"), "click", function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

My actual requirement here is, if any anchor clicked then only that one anchor have to get the event. But here what ever anchor you click the event if fired for all the anchors i.e., four times. I know that's how delegate works but I need some way to make this event fire only once as per my request. Any work around?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I tried your code, I only get one alert when I click on an anchor. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2r3ZA/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$("div").delegate($(".SameClass"), "click", function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
  $(this).addClass('clicked')
  alert("Clicked");
}});
```